# Button toggle to switch between images nd the text display on it/ raphael js/ javascript / html

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael

In my current assignment I got:

Create a toggle button on the html page that visually indicates what state it is in by changing the text displayed on it (e.g. changes between “up” and “down”, or “smiling” and “not smiling”) and by switching between two images, as well.
a. Hint: you will have to use a “state” variable outside the button’s listener callback function to re- member the button’s state between event callbacks.
4. Use the toggle button to toggle the mouth between a smile and a frown. In your button ‘click’ listener, check the button’s state with an ‘if’ statement to control whether you are going to make a smile or a frown.

I am quite confused as I searched in web - there are so many ways to create a button, in Html or in css.

Can somebody post a similar example please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the element.click and provide a callback click function. In this case the callback is the update function.

In the update function, check for the current src, i.e. the source for the image element. Update the src of the image and the text of the button accordingly.

I have also made it interactable in the image part. If not required just remove this line

```
imageElem.click(update);
```

```js
var imageElem = document.getElementById('test_Img'),
  buttonElem = document.getElementById('test_Btn'),
  img1 = 'http://www.fantazia.org.uk/images/600px-Smiley_svg_small.png',
  img2 = 'http://www.clipartsgram.com/image/2060213170-sad-smiley-face-clipart-mclpbaqca.png';

imageElem.addEventListener("click", update);
buttonElem.addEventListener("click", update);

function update() {
  var src, text;

  if (imageElem.src === img1) {
    src = img2;
    text = 'Sad';
  } else {
    src = img1;
    text = 'Smile';
  }
  buttonElem.value = text;
  imageElem.src = src;
}
```

```html
<input type = 'button' id="test_Btn" value = 'Smile'/>
<img id="test_Img" src='http://www.fantazia.org.uk/images/600px-Smiley_svg_small.png' />
```

Comment: Tkx for ur answer Ayan guess m getting wt u said but when i tried to run in my "main.js" file this "$" appear as an error  "not defined " in the developer tools in google, in the classes i hv never  seeing such a sign. Is this coming from a Jquery ?? I still don't get wt is that.. can u tell me how can I hv the same result only by javascript ?

Comment: Yea absolutely. That $ was undefined as jquery was not getting defined. Have updated the code and remove any library dependency. Just pure JS.